# CAShapeLayer with border and fill color and rounding

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation

How do I use CAShapeLayer to draw a line that has both a border color, border width and fill color?

Here's what I've tried, but it's only ever blue...

```
self.lineShape.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.lineShape.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.lineShape.lineWidth = 100;
self.lineShape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
self.lineShape.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:self.lineStart];
[path addLineToPoint:self.lineEnd];
self.lineShape.path = path.CGPath;
```

Comment: for those who looking for "Why border doesn't show up":
change `borderWidth` to `lineWidth` & `borderColor` to `strokeColor `

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Swift 3+ extension method (combined from AechoLiu answer below):

```swift
// Usage:
self.btnGroup.roundCorner([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 4.0, borderColor: UIColor.red, borderWidth: 1.0)

// Apply round corner and border. An extension method of UIView.
public func roundCorner(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {

let path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.cgPath
self.layer.mask = mask

let borderPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

}
```

Objective-C:

```
self.lineShapeBorder = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
self.lineShapeBorder.zPosition = 0.0f;
self.lineShapeBorder.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.lineShapeBorder.lineWidth = 25;
self.lineShapeBorder.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
self.lineShapeBorder.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
     
self.lineShapeFill = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[self.lineShapeBorder addSublayer:self.lineShapeFill];
self.lineShapeFill.zPosition = 0.0f;
self.lineShapeFill.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.lineShapeFill.lineWidth = 20.0f;
self.lineShapeFill.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
self.lineShapeFill.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
  
// ...
    
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:self.lineStart];
[path addLineToPoint:self.lineEnd];
// call addLineToPoint over and over to create the outline for the shape
self.lineShapeBorder.path = self.lineShapeFill.path = path.CGPath;
```

Also calling out @FarrasDoko comment to try changing `borderWidth` to `lineWidth` and `borderColor` to `strokeColor`.

Comment: I've had poor luck using just a single path and shape layer, so sticking with this answer still :)

Comment: Combined swift + obj answer for easier consumption of programmers

Comment: Could you indicate the source of Swift version after editing ? Thank you .

Answer (score 9):

If you set the layer's `fillColor` property to something other than `nil` or transparent, the layer will fill its path.

If you set the layer's `lineWidth` to a number larger than zero and you set its `strokeColor` to something other than `nil` or transparent, the layer will stroke its path.

If you set all of those properties, the layer will fill *and* stroke its path.  It draws the stroke after the fill.

The layer's path must actually enclose some area in order for it to fill anything.  In your post, you set the path like this:

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:self.lineStart];
[path addLineToPoint:self.lineEnd];
self.lineShape.path = path.CGPath;
```

That path contains a single line segment.  It doesn't enclose any area, so the layer has nothing to fill.

Comment: So I would need to have my path be a polygon then?

Comment: @PsychoDad Your path can be a polygon, or it can have curved sides.  It must have non-zero area.  A single line segment has zero area.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3. an extension method of `UIView`.

```
// Usage:
self.btnGroup.roundCorner([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 4.0, borderColor: UIColor.red, borderWidth: 1.0)

// Apply round corner and border. An extension method of UIView.
public func roundCorner(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask

    let borderPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```