# rounded corner to UITextField Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, user-experience

I have two textfield (username & password) and want to make top rounded corner for username and bottom rounded corner for password as per attachment.

[image]

Comment: see this and Apply on textField..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679886/how-to-make-a-uiview-with-optional-rounded-corners-and-border/22680538#22680538

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create a `UIView`.

Put your two text fields in the `UIView`. 
Remove the border style of `UITextField`.

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
yourView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below steps

STEP 1:Import QuartzCore framework in you class:

```
      #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

STEP 2:Apply the coding

```
      textField.layer.cornerRadius=6.0f;
      textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
      textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
      textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f; 

         or

      [textField.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
      [textField.layer setBorderWidth:2.o];
      [textField.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners cornerRadii:(CGSize)cornerRadii
```

Example:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:textField.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
textField.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be write CALayer extension. **Swift 3.x - 4.x**

```
extension CALayer {

    func addRadius(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, view: UIView) {
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.bounds = view.frame
        mask.position = view.center
        mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        view.layer.mask = mask
    }

    func addRadius(radius: CGFloat) {
        self.cornerRadius = radius
    }  
}
```

Use of

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var messageTextField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            messageTextField.layer.addRadius(radius: 8.0)
        }
    }
```

**Hope your help :)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full code sample:

import UIKit

```
class RoundedTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 //self.frame.size.height/2
        self.clipsToBounds = false

        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```